# Keyboard shortcut to format statements in Sqlyog?

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

What is the keyboard shortcut to pretty-format statements in Sqlyog?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

did you mean to this ?

```
SQL Formatter
F12         Format Current Query
Ctrl+F12        Format Selected Query
Shift+F12       Format All Queries
```

in the sqlyog , click on menu **help -> keyword shortcuts** , and we get all the list

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: These shortcuts are not working for some queries. The formating is not working for some specific queries even when I try with the UI options to Format. Any idea?